# Ubuntu Touch, install GUI

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, gui

Will Ubuntu Touch have an install GUI, like cyanogenmod  does, in the future?

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ppCsLEeb9Hw

Answer (score 0):

There is [MultiROM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tassadar.multirommgr&hl=en) Manager for Android devices which allows easy installation and dual booting. Read about it also [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/dual-boot-android-ubuntu-touch-or-firefox-os-on-nexus-4-7-with-multirom/).

Probably there are also some Ubuntu developers that (will) work on that.